# Contar la cantidad de veces que compara esta funcion de clasificación por inserción

Tags: python

Estoy intentando usar un contador para conocer la cantidad de veces que una función de clasificación por inserción compara los valores, pero tengo un problema de lógica.

Mi idea es: inicializar un contador, agregar ese contador dentro del ciclo while de modo que cada vez que se repita, sume un uno (1), y por fuera tener otro contador que cuente las veces que no entra al while, pues si no entra al while es porque también comparó.

Dado que mi objetivo es saber cuantas comparaciones hace la función, me pareció esta la solución más sencilla, pero no estoy seguro del todo.

Agradezco cualquier aporte, gracias de antemano :)

```py
def insertion_sort(array):

    cont = 0

    for i in range(1, len(array)):
        print(array)

        x = array[i]
        j = i

        while j > 0 and array[j - 1] > x:
            array[j] = array[j -1]
            j = j - 1
            cont +=1
        cont +=1

        array[j] = x

    return cont

array = [50, 30, 40, 10, 20]
```

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: La cuenta está correcta.